# Python; User Prompts; choose multiple files

Tags: python, file, user-interface, prompt

I would like to have my code bring up a window where you can select multiple files within a folder and it assigns these filenames to elements of a list.

Currently, I can only select a single file at a time and it assigns the filename to a single variable.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `askopenfilenames` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate all that in a function:

```
def get_filename_from_user(message):
  root = Tk()
  root.withdraw()
  filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title=message)
  return filename
```

Then you can call it as many times as you like:

```
filename1 = get_filename_from_user('select the first file!')
filename2 = get_filename_from_user('select another one!')
filename3 = get_filename_from_user('select one more!')
```

Unless you have tons of files you want to select. Then you probably want to use `askopenfilenames`:

```
files = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose a file or LOTS!')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from easygui import fileopenbox
files = []
#how many file you want choice
fileCount = int(input("How many file need open"))
for x in range(fileCount):
    files.append(fileopenbox())
print(files)
```

Comment: The code in the question uses Tkinter, not EasyGUI.